# What form field type to use for arrays (lists)

Tags: django

I'm expecting json data to be submitted to my form, with one field being an array of up to N strings of M chars each. The model uses a `django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField` - what type of field should I declare it as in the form?

For example:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=M), size=N)

class FooForm(forms.Form):
    barStrings = is there an inbuilt Field I can use here?
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any inbuilt Fields that handle lists, so it's necessary to write a simple one, for example:

```
class ListField(forms.Field):
    """ Custom field that can handle list input """
    def clean(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, list):
            raise ValidationError("Please provide an array")
```